Android app returning 401 error on API call with token, works fine on iOS
I am working on a mobile application where login works perfectly on both iOS and Android. However, after logging in, when I try to make subsequent API requests with the authorization token on Android, I consistently get a 401 Unauthorized error. The same API calls work fine on iOS.
export const poster = async ({url, method = 'POST', body}: PosterType) => {
  const {cookie} = store.getState().userReducer;
  // Only add Authorization header if cookie exists

  return await axios({
    url,
    method: method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${cookie}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    data: body,
    withCredentials: false,

    // mode: 'cors',
  })
    .then(async value => {
      const data = await value.data;

      if (!value.status) {
        throw new Error(data.message ?? data?.error?.message);
      }
      return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(error), 'errorerrorerrorerror');
      throw error;
    });
};

Why is this issue happening on Android only? What could cause the headers or token to not be sent or parsed properly on Android?
How can I fix this issue on Android to ensure that the authorization token is passed correctly and authenticated by the server, as it does on iOS?

Ensure that you have added this line in manifest file inside android folder.
Beacus if you are targeting devices with API level 28+, it requires additional security to handle cleartext traffic (HTTP). So either your url should be secured i.e HTTPS or you have to add this permission in manifext file
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
</application>

